# JSON string as input with Cosmonaut (CosmosDb)

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

The .NET SDK of CosmosDB allows JSON string as input as below:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write("{JSON_string_here}");
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    ResponseMessage response = await this.container.CreateItemStreamAsync(stream, new PartitionKey("{PK_here}"));

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Handle and log exception
    }
    else
    {
        //code logic here
    }
};
```

Does Cosmonaut too allow JSON string as input to create an item in the container?

Answer (score 0):

By using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` package, there are two methods for create items in container:

```
public abstract Task<ItemResponse<T>> CreateItemAsync<T>(T item, PartitionKey? partitionKey = null, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

public abstract Task<ResponseMessage> CreateItemStreamAsync(Stream streamPayload, PartitionKey partitionKey, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

I find a workaround for your request, you can take advantage of `Newtonsoft.Json` package.

Here is the quick sample I used to test:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static string EndpointUrl = "https://jackdemo.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static string PrimaryKey = "AWgnKF********odqAkQwA==";
        private static CosmosClient cosmosClient;
        private static Database database;
        private static Container container;
        private static string databaseId = "db";
        private static string containerId = "demo";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey);
            database = cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId).Result;
            container = database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "/key").Result;
            string json = "{\"id\":\"bbb\",\"key\":\"bbb\"}";
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            container.CreateItemAsync<Object>(obj).Wait();
            cosmosClient.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible using Cosmonaut.

Comment: Checked in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut), I am afraid that it is not supported.